# wso2esb 4.8.1 and 4.9.0 different behaviour onError

Tags: wso2-esb

I have a registered onError sequence.

In version 4.8.1 SOAP envelop is available in onError sequence
while in 4.9.0 it is not.

in order to access SOAP message content in 4.9.0 after error (in onError sequence) I always have to copy it to some temp variable initially. it is very inconvenient.

could it be a bug or is it a new "feature" of 4.9.0?

this is my fault sequence. if i remove enrich mediator envelope comes empty from the sequence with an error. Without enrich mediator message contains empty soap envelope. It can be seen in the output of the log mediator and in the message stored in RabbitMQ backend. Actually, it is onError sequence of XXXXNotifySendSequence sequence (I added them both for the reference).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="XXXXNotifyErrorSequence" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <log level="full">
                    <property name="mssg" expression="get-property('mssg')"/>
                    <property name="retry_count" expression="get-property('retry_count')"/>
                </log>
  <filter xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xpath="get-property('mssg')">
    <then>
      <enrich>
        <source clone="true" property="mssg" type="property"/>
        <target type="envelope"/>
      </enrich>
      <property name="mssg" action="remove"/>
    </then>
    <else/>
  </filter>



  <filter xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns3="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xpath="get-property('retry_count')">
        <then>
            <property name="retry_count" expression="number(get-property('retry_count'))+1" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <filter xpath="get-property('retry_count') > 5">
                <then>
                    <log>
                        <property name="Dropping--Count" expression="get-property('retry_count')"/>
                    </log>
                    <drop/>
                </then>
                <else>
                    <sequence key="XXXXNotifySendSequence"/>
                </else>
            </filter>
        </then>
        <else>
            <property name="retry_count" value="1" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <clone continueParent="true">
                <target>
                    <sequence>
                        <makefault version="soap11">
                            <code xmlns:soap11Env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" value="soap11Env:VersionMismatch"/>
                            <reason expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"/>
                        </makefault>
                        <send/>
                    </sequence>
                </target>
            </clone>
        </else>
    </filter>

    <clone>
        <target>
            <sequence>
                <log level="custom">
                    <property name="STORE" value="store the message"/>
                </log>
                <store messageStore="XXXXRabbitMQNative"/>
            </sequence>
        </target>
    </clone>

</sequence>
```

this is the sequence calling onError sequence

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="XXXXNotifySendSequence"
  onError="XXXXNotifyErrorSequence" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <log level="full">
    <property name="XXXX" value="request start"/>
  </log>
  <enrich>
    <source clone="true" type="envelope"/>
    <target property="mssg" type="property"/>
  </enrich>
  <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
  <call>
    <endpoint key="HTTPEndpoint"/>
  </call>
  <log level="full">
    <property name="XXXX" value="request end"/>
  </log>
</sequence>
```

Comment: can you share your fault sequence to see what you mean by not available?

Comment: I have added onError sequence

Answer (score 0):

I am not much sure why you written fault sequence in that way. but when i change like bellow its working. no need to enrich and assign to other property

Sequence:(same as yours - untouched)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="XXXXNotifySendSequence"
    onError="XXXXNotifyErrorSequence" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <log level="full">
        <property name="XXXX" value="request start"/>
    </log>
    <enrich>
        <source clone="true" type="envelope"/>
        <target action="replace" property="mssg" type="property"/>
    </enrich>
    <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
    <call>
        <endpoint key="HTTPEndpoint"/>
    </call>
    <log level="full">
        <property name="XXXX" value="request end"/>
    </log>
</sequence>
```

fault sequence:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="XXXXNotifyErrorSequence" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <log>
        <property expression="get-property('ERROR_CODE')"
            name="========error-code=========" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
        <property expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"
            name="========error-message=========" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    </log>
    <makefault version="soap11">
        <code value="soap11Env:VersionMismatch" xmlns:soap11Env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
        <reason expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
        <role>sample</role>
        <detail>sample detail</detail>
    </makefault>
    <send/>
</sequence>
```

proxy: to call sequence

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="samplecall"
       transports="http,https"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target inSequence="XXXXNotifySendSequence"/>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

response: (since end point is not defined)

```
 <soapenv:Fault xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <faultcode xmlns:soap11Env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">soap11Env:VersionMismatch</faultcode>
   <faultstring>Couldn't find the endpoint with the key : HTTPEndpoint</faultstring>
   <faultactor>sample</faultactor>
   <detail>sample detail</detail>
</soapenv:Fault>
```

in log:

```
2015-11-08 17:19:55,250]  INFO - LogMediator To: /services/samplecall.samplecallHttpSoap11Endpoint, WSAction: urn:mediate, SOAPAction: urn:mediate, MessageID: urn:uuid:106d763f-cdc1-43d2-98a9-63d22d17eb81, Direction: request, XXXX = request start, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body/></soapenv:Envelope>
[2015-11-08 17:19:55,252]  INFO - LogMediator To: /services/samplecall.samplecallHttpSoap11Endpoint, WSAction: urn:mediate, SOAPAction: urn:mediate, MessageID: urn:uuid:106d763f-cdc1-43d2-98a9-63d22d17eb81, Direction: request, ========error-code========= = 305100, ========error-message========= = Couldn't find the endpoint with the key : HTTPEndpoint
```

Comment: Ok. but where is the content of SOAP envelope? can it be accessed in onError sequence?

Comment: in case of failure I store the message in an external queue, then using sampling message I processor read messages from queue and to process them again. the idea is taken from -  http://charith.wickramaarachchi.org/2012/05/another-message-redelivery-pattern-with.html.